# Extract MySQL DB Info to one txt file

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help moving some databade information to one `.txt` file.

My table looks like this: [image]

And what I need is to get each DB line into this example bellow to one `.txt` file:

```
<object id="object (sql) (1)" breakable="true" interior="2" collisions="true" alpha="255" model="2885" doublesided="true" scale="1" dimension="1156" posX="44" posY="2033.2002" posZ="1047.2" rotX="0" rotY="0" rotZ="270"></object>
```

I think it should be somthing like this:

```
<object id="object (sql) (.id.)" breakable=".breakable." interior=".interior." collisions="true" alpha=".alpha." model=".model." doublesided=".doublesided." scale=".scale." dimension=".dimension." posX=".posX." posY=".posY." posZ=".posZ." rotX=".rotX." rotY=".rotY." rotZ=".rotZ."></object>
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: You are trying to concatenat some result of  a query ? ... show the code you are using

Comment: why don't you just export it from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql --xml -u username -p database_name table_name > table_name.xml
```

use this command from mysql console or export the database from phpmyadmin as said by [Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii)